# PlayerDeathEvent drops don't call PlayerDropItemEvent

Tags: java, bukkit

I'd like to add every item a player drops into an `ArrayList` in a `HashMap`

```
public HashMap<Arena, ArrayList<Item>> drops = new HashMap<Arena, ArrayList<Item>>();
```

If a player drops the item with <kbd>Q</kbd> everything works great, but if a player dies, the items he drops don't call the `PlayerDropItemEvent` and in `PlayerDeathEvent` it only exists

```
e.getDrops()
```

and that is just a

```
List<ItemStack>
```

and not a

```
List<Item>
```

because these items aren't dropped in that time.

Now how can I add these dropped items (entities) to the List?

Comment: You cannot. Bukkit does not pass the `PlayerItemDropEvent` for item entities spawned for any other reason than the player dropping them with the drop key or tossing it outside inventory area.

Comment: Well but why then just someone does give a -1 ?
I asked a question, that was never asked before and why then just someone gives me a -1? That's not fair

Answer (score 1):

Storing the `Item` entity that is provided with the drop event in a list might, as far as I can tell, lead to unwanted behavior similar to how storing `Player` variables for longer than short periods of time is often advised against. When a player logs out the `Player` object might still be accidentally stored somewhere else in a list somewhere, and similarly the dropped items could be picked up only ticks later (destroying the entity and transferring them as `ItemStack`s to the player's inventory) or be de-spawned because of various other reasons. In this case the entity would still be in your list (unless you check for all these scenarios somehow, which would probably be quite tedious) and could potentially cause memory leaks as far as I understand it.

I would use `ItemStack`s in your list to keep track of the items a player has dropped, which you could do by calling the `getItemStack()` method from the `Item` entity returned in the drop event (and like you mentioned, the death event already provides the items in `ItemStack` form).

I thought that if you absolutely needed to store the drops in `Item` entity form, you could potentially spawn the `ItemStack`s in as dropped items using `player.getWorld().dropItem(player.getLocation(), drop)` where `drop` is an ItemStack in the death event `getDrops()` `ArrayList`, although that would result in the dropped items being duplicated, and removing them again using `item.remove()` after you've spawned each entity in and added it to your list would most likely cause similar issues as described above (although it might be worth a try to see what happens).